# Filter Duplicates in UNION with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I am trying to remove the duplicate entries which are being caused by date values being different. I tried to use min(date) in group by but that's not allowed

For example in getting back the following 2 rows when all I need is the 1st

```
MasterCustomerId    NewClubKeyId    DateAssigned
000000201535        K18752          2014-08-13 20:25:18.717
000000201535        K18752          2015-01-08 00:41:03.037
```

Here is my query. Any ideas? Thanks

```
SELECT  nc.CreatorMasterCustomerId MasterCustomerId,nc.NewClubKeyId,MIN(nc.DateCreated) DateAssigned
FROM NewClub nc
WHERE nc.IsActive = 1 AND nc.NewClubKeyId IS NOT NULL AND nc.DateCreated IS NOT NULL
AND nc.DateCreated >='2013-10-10'
GROUP BY nc.CreatorMasterCustomerId,nc.NewClubKeyId,nc.DateCreated

UNION

SELECT   ncb.MasterCustomerId,nc.NewClubKeyId,MIN(ncb.DateCreated) DateAssigned
FROM NewClubBuilder ncb
JOIN NewClub nc ON nc.Id = ncb.NewClubId
WHERE nc.IsActive = 1 AND nc.NewClubKeyId IS NOT NULL AND ncb.DateCreated IS NOT NULL
AND ncb.DateCreated >='2013-10-10'
GROUP BY ncb.MasterCustomerId,nc.NewClubKeyId,ncb.DateCreated
```

Per the suggestion from @suslov below, I implemented the query as described and it works well. Here it is:

```
select 
t.MasterCustomerId,
t.NewClubKeyId,
MIN(t.DateCreated)DateAssigned
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT nc.CreatorMasterCustomerId MasterCustomerId,nc.NewClubKeyId,nc.DateCreated
    FROM NewClub nc
    WHERE nc.IsActive = 1 AND nc.NewClubKeyId IS NOT NULL AND nc.DateCreated IS NOT NULL
    AND nc.DateCreated >='2013-10-10'

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT  ncb.MasterCustomerId,nc.NewClubKeyId,ncb.DateCreated
    FROM NewClubBuilder ncb
    JOIN NewClub nc ON nc.Id = ncb.NewClubId
    WHERE nc.IsActive = 1 AND nc.NewClubKeyId IS NOT NULL AND ncb.DateCreated IS NOT NULL
    AND ncb.DateCreated >='2013-10-10'
)t

GROUP BY t.MasterCustomerId,t.NewClubKeyId
```

Comment: Why do you need to do the union at all? It looks like you're pulling the data from the same table.

Comment: You could do `SELECT MasterCustomerId, NewClubId, Max(DateAssigned) FROM ( your query here ) GROUP BY MasterCustomerId, NewClubId`

Comment: @SLin - join are different

Comment: @ughai Yes I realize there is a join in the second one but it looks to me like it can be just one query.

Comment: Have you tried a subquery that gets the top 1 date where the CreatorMasterCustomerid = nc.CreatorMasterCustomerId AND the NewClubKeyId = nc.NewClubKeyId and  nc.DateCreated >='2013-10-10' then use that subquery in your where clause instead of >='2013-10-10' so it would be nc.datecreated = subquery result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your `select` with `union` as a temporary table and then `select` from it and do a `group by` you did before without `DateCreated` field.

```
select t.CreatorMasterCustomerId as MasterCustomerId
     , t..NewClubKeyId
     , min(t.DateCreated) as DateAssigned
from (<...>) t
group by t.MasterCustomerId
       , t.NewClubKeyId
```

Comment: Thanks, @suslov I used your idea